# Jquery select multiple drag /drop

Tags: jquery, select, drag-and-drop

I want to select multiple list from one box and drag it in to another box is it possible by using jquery ?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774755/jquery-sortable-select-and-drag-multiple-list-items ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, look at the j[QueryUI framework](http://jqueryui.com/) - specifically the draggable, droppable, selectable and sortable plugins.

Demos [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#connect-lists).