# Select and Drag Multiple List Items (jQuery ui sortable)

Tags: jquery, user-interface

I have found great solution (last answer):

[jQuery Sortable - Select and Drag Multiple List Items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774755/jquery-sortable-select-and-drag-multiple-list-items)

http://jsfiddle.net/hQnWG/480/

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
    <li>Six</li>
</ul>
```

**JavaScript (with jQuery and jQuery UI):**

```
$("ul").on('click', 'li', function (e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) {
        $(this).toggleClass("selected");
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass('selected');
    }
}).sortable({
    connectWith: "ul",
    delay: 150, //Needed to prevent accidental drag when trying to select
    revert: 0,
    helper: function (e, item) {
        var helper = $('<li/>');
        if (!item.hasClass('selected')) {
            item.addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
        }
        var elements = item.parent().children('.selected').clone();
        item.data('multidrag', elements).siblings('.selected').remove();
        return helper.append(elements);
    },
    stop: function (e, info) {
        info.item.after(info.item.data('multidrag')).remove();
    }

});
```

It works great but when I'm dragging two or more elements JS console in Google Chrome shows this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'insertBefore' of null

How do I fix it?

Comment: No errors on Safari `6.0.3` and OS X `10.8.3`. Also I don't see `insertBefore()` in your code? What the problem is that a jQuery selector probably failed `var test = $('#myNoneExcistingElement');` and `console.log(test);` will print `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: No errors in `25.0` chrome

Comment: @DavidChase because the `.insertBefore()` method is absent in the example ;) Or it is either used as substitute in another method, but can't confirm that for sure.

Comment: @Allendar i see that, i just wanted to share my test :)

Comment: Errors stil show up (newest Chrome). Just select two elements from first list (one and two) and drag them **inside** only this list. After 2 or 3 actions u will get error. I count over 10 errors in a few seconds.

Comment: Happens with me too. Everything seems to be working though, but this error is annoying...

Answer (score 4):

I think its a bug in jquery-UI _rearrange function ...
so i did a hack which overrides that method... 
Insert the below code after  dom ready ...that will fix the issue

```
$.ui.sortable.prototype._rearrange = function (event, i, a, hardRefresh) {

                a ? a[0].appendChild(this.placeholder[0]) : (i.item[0].parentNode) ? i.item[0].parentNode.insertBefore(this.placeholder[0], (this.direction === "down" ? i.item[0] : i.item[0].nextSibling)) : i.item[0];
                this.counter = this.counter ? ++this.counter : 1;
                var counter = this.counter;

                this._delay(function () {
                    if (counter === this.counter) {
                        this.refreshPositions(!hardRefresh); //Precompute after each DOM insertion, NOT on mousemove
                    }
                });

            }
```

here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/r83zY/