# jQuery UI Selectable Across Connected Sortable Lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-selectable

I have successfully managed to hack together (with the help of other posts), this example

[here](http://jsbin.com/egiqad/1/edit) (code and live example)

which is a jQuery UI sortable and selectable comprised of three connected lists. There is also a restriction on it so that only one item may be selected at a time.

If you look at the demo you will see that selection is only possible across items of the same list. My question is how I can make selection go across multiple connected lists.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11528315 perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping around your sortables with a div. For example: `<div id="sortables">`.
Then change your selector from:

```
$("#list1, #list2, #list3").selectable
```

to:

```
$("#sortables").selectable
```

Then add this line as a [selectable option](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectable/#option-filter):

```
filter: "li",
```

This way will make only the `<li>` elements selectable within the "sortables" div.