# select box with multiple values turning on and off

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I've got a select box in a form with multiple="multiple" switched on.

At the moment I can obviously hold Ctrl if I want to select multiple items, but what I really want it the option to just click any i like, and they just get selected or deselected when clicked.

I guess kinda like a whole list of checkboxes, but I really don't want them as checkboxes, I want them all as a dropdown.

Is this even possible? Maybe with jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think going with checkboxes is not a bad way. Check out http://jqueryui.com/button/#checkbox. Then you can style the buttons like a list with `display: block` etc.

Comment: Thanks, the radio buttons in this page was perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something a little different like this: [jQuery Sortable - Select and Drag Multiple List Items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774755/jquery-sortable-select-and-drag-multiple-list-items)

The demo shown there works as you requested in an appealing way.