# I can select, but I can't drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have 5 by 5 grid filled with letters. I was able to write the jQuery that allows me to make each individual tile selectable and it highlights when I select it. I'm also trying to make the tile draggable. I googled and and found that jQuery allows statement chaining if I used the format

```
$(selector).fn1().fn2();
```

However, I can't seem to get the statement chaining to work for me. Here's the jQuery I used followed by the entire HTML. My The tiles still select and highlight, but I can't get the tiles to drag individually. Can someone tell me what I did wrong?

*the code i used : `$("#squares").selectable().draggable();`

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Name</title>
</head>

  <link rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" href="board.css">
  <link href="scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
      $("#squares").selectable().draggable();
      });

  </script>

<body>

<ol id="squares">
    <li class="square-default">A</li>
  <li class="square-default">D</li>
  <li class="square-default">K</li>
  <li class="square-default">Y</li>
  <li class="square-default">I</li>
  <li class="square-default">T</li>
  <li class="square-default">A</li>
  <li class="square-default">S</li>
  <li class="square-default">E</li>
  <li class="square-default">C</li>
  <li class="square-default">R</li>
  <li class="square-default">B</li>
  <li class="square-default">A</li>
  <li class="square-default">S</li>
  <li class="square-default">T</li>
  <li class="square-default">Y</li>
  <li class="square-default">L</li>
  <li class="square-default">P</li>
  <li class="square-default">B</li>
  <li class="square-default">C</li>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you mean that you *can* select but can not drag?

Comment: Do you mean that you can not select but can drag?

Comment: hey. I can select, but I can not drag. Sorry, I edited the title.

Comment: So you want to be able to drag the whole list? or just each list item?

Comment: For selectable and draggable take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774755/jquery-sortable-select-and-drag-multiple-list-items