# How to drag one or more items to an element using both Draggable and Selectable JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'd like to know how to drag one or more items (individual Person records in my case, via their avatar photo) to a  target (in my case a list of cities) and then update the database for the dragged items with details of the item they were dragged to.

I have this working for single items at the moment.

I have a sidebar with a list of locations which I retrieve from a database with EntityFramework:

```
<ul>
<li class="droppable">
    <span>Sydney</span>
</li>
<li class="droppable">
    <span>Brisbane</span>
</li>
<li class="droppable">
    <span>Melbourne</span>
</li>
</ul>
```

In my main window I have a grid of people's images and I'm using Jquery UI selectable to enable these to be selected:

```
<ul class="people-list" id="selectable">
    @foreach (var item in Model.People)
    {
        <li>
            <img src="@item.Photo" style="width:100%" class="img-polaroid" />                
        </li>
    }
</ul>

 $(function () {
    $("#selectable").selectable({
        selected: function (event, ui) {
            if ($(ui.selected).hasClass('click-selected')) {
                $(ui.selected).removeClass('ui-selected click-selected');

            } else {
                $(ui.selected).addClass('click-selected');

            }
        },
        unselected: function (event, ui) {
            $(ui.unselected).removeClass('click-selected');
        }
    });

});
```

What I'd like to do, is that once the user has selected one or more people, for them to be able to drag the selected people to one of the Locations, and then update the database.

So if the user drags PersonID 4,5 and 9, to 'Sydney' then I need to update the database asyncronously to perform this.

I've added JQuery Draggable and Droppable and I can drag individual people to one of the Locations, and then update the database, but I can't get it to work with selectable to allow multiple items to be selected.

```
$(function () {
    $(".img-polaroid").draggable({
        containment: "document",
        helper: 'clone',
        opacity: 0.70,
        zIndex: 10000,

    });
    $(".droppable").droppable({
        hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
        tolerance: "pointer",
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/Person/UpdateLocations/' + $(this).attr("id") + '|' + $(ui.draggable).attr("id"),
                success: function (data) {
                    $('.draggable').draggable('destroy');
                    $('#successMsg').empty();
                    $('#successMsg').append(data);
                    $('#successDiv').show();
                    $('.draggable').draggable({ revert: true });
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you looked at this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/15301704/1480215

Comment: You could try this https://github.com/someshwara/MultiDraggable

Comment: Or after choosing the multiple elements, you drag and drop one, then programmatically drag and drop the rest with something like this http://j-ulrich.github.io/jquery-simulate-ext/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find out that .selectable() and .draggable() are not working on a same element. My suggestion is to create your own multi-select behaviour.

### Embedding value (id) to HTML elements

Embed ids, as value, to HTML elements accordingly both for the cities and persons, eq : `<li class="droppable" data-val="sydney"><span>Sydney</span> </li>` and `<img src="" class="img-polaroid" data-val="4"/>`.

### Imitating Multi-select

Every selected element will be tagged by specific class, defined in `selectedClass = "ui-selected"`. This class will be toggled by click event. An element may not selected on the drag event, therefore we need to add `selectedClass` on `draggable.start`.

### Drag

`.draggable` only works on single dragged element (CMIIW), thus we move the selected element by changing the `top` and `left` properties of the elements. Set `position=relative` of the `#selectable` element.

### Drop

Actions need to be done on `droppable.drop` callback : Prepare data and perform AJAX request.
If the AJAX request succeed the selectable elements will be removed and update message. If AJAX request failed the selectable elements are going to placed back on their original position.

Please take a look on the example : http://jsfiddle.net/marson/zSCAb/131/.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Good answer and in the JS Fiddle I can multi select - but I can't seem to drop

Comment: To simplify the code, I replaced the `success` callback (AJAX) function you created to `//console.log("ajax request")` statement. To remove the `<li />`s of the selected `<img />`s, add `$("."+selectedClass).parent("li").remove()` on `success` or `complete` callback function in your `$.ajax`

Comment: Please note I've updated the example (jsfiddle) and answer above. On drop events, AJAX request is executed and the selected elements will be removed upon successful response.