# jQuery UI Sortable with multiple elements throws "TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of null"

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to implement drag & drop with multiple elements following the example from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15301704/192594): http://jsfiddle.net/hQnWG/614/

The example is working fine with jQuery 1.9.1 and jQuery UI 1.9.2 (up to 1.10.1), but as soon as I use newer versions, like jQuery 1.11.3 and jQuery UI 1.10.2 or newer I get the following issues.

When selecting multiple elements and start dragging the bottom most selected element slowly to the top, right before it would snap to the next position, the following JS error is beeing thrown:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of null
   at t.(/hQnWG/614/anonymous function).(anonymous function)._rearrange (https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js:7:15171)
   at t.(/hQnWG/614/anonymous function).(anonymous function)._rearrange (https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js:5:5028)
   at t.(/hQnWG/614/anonymous function).(anonymous function)._mouseDrag (https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js:7:6)
   at t.(/hQnWG/614/anonymous function).(anonymous function)._mouseDrag (https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js:5:5028)
   at t.(/hQnWG/614/anonymous function).(anonymous function)._mouseMove (https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js:5:12328)
   at t.(/hQnWG/614/anonymous function).(anonymous function)._mouseMove (https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js:5:5028)
   at HTMLDocument.o._mouseCapture._mouseDistanceMet._mouseDelayMet._mouseMoveDelegate (VM687 jquery-ui.min.js:5)
   at HTMLDocument.dispatch (VM251 jquery-1.11.3.min.js:4)
   at HTMLDocument.r.handle (VM251 jquery-1.11.3.min.js:4)
```

Here is a fork of the example jsfiddle with upgraded jQuery versions: 
http://jsfiddle.net/v3p6wsk2/6/

I tried to debug it, but can't find any explanation how the parentNode of the dragged item can be null. 
[image]

I can't even find any hint in the [jQuery UI 1.10.2. change log](http://jqueryui.com/changelog/1.10.2/) about what changed that could break that script.

Unfortunately I am not able to change the version in the project I'm working on. Is there any possibility to get this working with the mentioned versions?

Comment: Not a complete example. Please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve We need to see your code. Also, I suspect that you may need to define `items` option for Sortable.

Comment: The second jsfiddle link is actually the code with errors and where I isolated the problem. The only difference to the first jsfiddle is in the lib versions.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, it was not clear. I attempted to replicate the issue as you described it. I dragged 1 item, no issue. I dragged 2 items, no issue. I dragged 2 items "slowly" (could you define what you mean by slowly?), no issue. I am testing in FireFox 59 (32-bit) on Ubuntu.

Comment: Wait, again, sorry, your post is not clear and I think I was looking at the wrong example (using jQuery 1.9.1). Will test in your version that has jQuery 1.11.3.

Comment: Noticed you were not using the Resourcess for fiddle correctly, moved jQuery to Resource section and tested: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/wzuak8as/1/ I am still unable to replicate the issue.

Comment: You are right, I wasn't clear enogh, sorry. I didn't use the resources from jsfiddle, because the latest jQuery version there is 1.9.1. As my project uses 1.12., the only way I found to use the same version was to add them as a <script> resource. Didn't know that I can add other resources, thanks for pointing that out.
I added a more precise description how I meant the dragging, I hope this helps reproducing it. I can reproduce the error in your jsfiddle too. Thanks a lot for your efforts.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I will test in both FireFox and Chromium. To clarify, when you say "*start dragging the bottom most element slowly to the top*", do you mean within the same list or the other list? Please be as detailed as possible. Current tests area: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/wzuak8as/21/

Comment: Ok, I have been able to replicate the Error in Chromium ONLY. Also, it is not a show stopper. I am still able to continue my drag and drop with proper functionality. Is this also the case for you? I am going to switch from the Minimized to the Uncompressed version to identify the exact code line that is failing.

Comment: You're right, I'm still able to continue the drag and drop. Sometimes however I'm losing some of the selected elements, only the element below the cursor remains, the others dissappeared. This is how I noticed the error messages and assumed that they are related. Unfortunately I can't reproduce this behavior in the example code and now I start doubting that it's caused by these errors.

Comment: Nevertheless it would be great if we could find the source of the problem. In the meantime I will try to find a way to reproduce the buggy behavior.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I can see, the problem is that the element on which the `parentNode.insertBefore` is called is one of the dragged elements (which was removed from the original table) and therefore really doesn't have a parent anymore.

What really get's me is that I think the problem is not directly within the `helper` or `stop` function but somewhere in between, as the error gets triggered right after the `sort`-event.

I have no idea where this problem originates as it's functioning with the older versions, but via trial&error I might have found a workaround for your problem.

Instead of removing the elements in your helper, you could just hide them and remove the hidden elements after inserting the dropped elements to the list.

See [twistys fiddle I just updated](https://jsfiddle.net/wzuak8as/87/).

This might solve your problem, although this doesn't fix (or even find) the cause for this problem.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfect for me. I wound up changing the onClick so that you could unselect a single click by clicking again: https://jsfiddle.net/wzuak8as/123/

Answer (score 2):

So the source of the problem lies here:

```
_rearrange: function(event, i, a, hardRefresh) {
  a ? a[0].appendChild(this.placeholder[0]) : i.item[0].parentNode.insertBefore(this.placeholder[0], (this.direction === "down" ? i.item[0] : i.item[0].nextSibling));

  //Various things done here to improve the performance:
  // 1. we create a setTimeout, that calls refreshPositions
  // 2. on the instance, we have a counter variable, that get's higher after every append
  // 3. on the local scope, we copy the counter variable, and check in the timeout, if it's still the same
  // 4. this lets only the last addition to the timeout stack through
  this.counter = this.counter ? ++this.counter : 1;
  var counter = this.counter;

  this._delay(function() {
    if(counter === this.counter) {
      this.refreshPositions(!hardRefresh); //Precompute after each DOM insertion, NOT on mousemove
    }
  });
}
```

When I generate the error with the Uncompressed version, I see:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of null
    at $.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._rearrange (https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js:4628:68)
    at $.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._rearrange (https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js:401:25)
    at $.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._mouseDrag (https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js:3879:11)
    at $.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._mouseDrag (https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js:401:25)
    at $.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._mouseMove (https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js:933:9)
    at $.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._mouseMove (https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js:401:25)
    at HTMLDocument._mouseMoveDelegate (https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js:911:16)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js:4:8549)
    at HTMLDocument.r.handle (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js:4:5252)
Location: jquery-ui.js:4628
```

The `_rearrange` function starts with a conditional action. If `a` exists, then `append` a placeholder Else `insertBefore()` the `parentNode` of a specific Element inside of an array.

So, my guess, is that `.insertBefore()` is the DOM Method and not the jQuery Method. Based on the structure, `parentNode` is returning a `null` element.

> **HTML DOM parentNode Property**
>
> Return Value: A Node object, representing the parent node of a node, or *null* if the node has no parent

Ok, so we identify that `i.item[0].parentNode` is retuning a `null` value and causes the issue.

I suspect the crux of this is that the `helper` has no wrapper, hence each item at `stop` has no `parent`; therefore, no `parentNode`. I think the fix will be to drop 1 item and then append after it the other elements or to append the elements in another callback event.

I will update this once I have more information.

Again, this is not always a show stopper and so far, only an issue in Chrome based browsers.

**Update 1**

Looks like switching this from `stop` to `update` callback has helped. Minor differences in the two:

> **stop( event, ui )**
>
> This event is triggered when sorting has stopped.

VS

> **update( event, ui )**
>
> This event is triggered when the user stopped sorting and the DOM position has changed.

I had hoped this would be the trick. I was not getting it initially after the update and then I did get it. Will have to keep working.

**Update 2**

This fiddle works without error in FF and Chromium: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/wzuak8as/99/

I was able to isolate the error in the creation of the `helper`. What I believe the issue was related to was this line of code:

```
return helper.append(elements);
```

So this code states that we are returning a jQuery Object, `helper`, which is a `<li>` element as a result for the anonymous function. At the same time we're attempting to append additional jQuery Objects, `elements` into the `<li>` element.

When I adjust the code to something like:

```
helper.append(elements);
return helper;
```

The error no longer presents itself.

I went back and looked at the same function in jQuery UI 1.9.2:

```
_rearrange: function(event, i, a, hardRefresh) {
  a ? a[0].appendChild(this.placeholder[0]) : i.item[0].parentNode.insertBefore(this.placeholder[0], (this.direction == 'down' ? i.item[0] : i.item[0].nextSibling));
  //Various things done here to improve the performance:
  // 1. we create a setTimeout, that calls refreshPositions
  // 2. on the instance, we have a counter variable, that get's higher after every append
  // 3. on the local scope, we copy the counter variable, and check in the timeout, if it's still the same
  // 4. this lets only the last addition to the timeout stack through
  this.counter = this.counter ? ++this.counter : 1;
  var counter = this.counter;
  this._delay(function() {
    if(counter == this.counter) this.refreshPositions(!hardRefresh); //Precompute after each DOM insertion, NOT on mousemove
  });
}
```

I am unable to find a difference in the two libraries. Nor can I find out why one operates without error and one does not. They should be the same.

<strike>In my testing, I have been able to run the code without error. I hope that this helps and you will mark it as the answer.</strike>

Developer tools were caching console results and I was not seeing the error appear. I went back to your original code, applied the change, and got the same error.